# Disconnecting or closing terminal does not run bash_logout

Tags: bash, .bash-logout

I have some group permission clean up commands I have piped to all users ~/.bash_logout on a shared web development server. However, we noticed that if a user uses disconnects or closing terminal to exit the ssh session, then the typical bash_logout script will not be run.

> Is there anyway to ensure that bash_logout is always run in the
> background – regardless of what method the user uses to disconnect?

I do not have root access, but solutions using root are welcome – as they may be helpful to others.

**(Extra Information)**
Want to know more about the group permissions clean up? Essentially, they are using a shared Conda environment, and running this cleanup ensures that anyone in our group can write, read, and execute the files in that conda environment.

**(Extra Information)**
And no I did not tell people to chmod 777 their bashrc and bash_login to get this to work. We are using an automated and non-root method to sync up subsections of all group users bashrc and bash_login. More details if you are interested. I can remotely alter everyones bachrc and bash_login when desired without permissions or root.

Comment: Ctrl-C does usually does not exit SSH sessions that run a shell on the remote side (Ctrl-D would). Can you clarify how Ctrl-C works in your environment?

Comment: Ctrl-C by default may not terminate bash nor end ssh session. Ctrl-C will work if ssh do not allocate terminal running other command in chain or when you terminate client itself via ~.^C You need to explain more how things are organized there.

Comment: @Wieland Oh my mistake, you are right! I just tested this. Let me ask the colleage that circumvented bash_logout what they did again. One moment...

Comment: @Wieland Okay editing the question now. They press the 'x' button on their windows machine – not Ctrl-X. I misread.

Comment: For what I understand you want to do, relying on the unreliable execution of a `.bash_logout` script is not going to work so well, as you have discovered. The bash manual details when it is, and is not, executed. There are other ways to detect when a user (or more specifically, the attached vtty/connection) terminates and then run the cleanup script at that point. As it is, you are asking the _users_ to clean up after themselves in a manner such as a bank asking them to "close the main bank vault when you are done, so no one can slip in and take all the money..."